# What is the difference between getRichStringCellValue() and getStringCellValue() methods of POI HSSFCell class?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read data stored in a Excel sheet using Java POI. I am confused with these two methods because both methods reutrn string value stored in the cell. Could anyone explain the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The important clue is to look @ the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html) and note the different return types.

getRichStringCellValue() returns the type of XSSFRichTextString while getStringCellValue() returns a plain old java String.

You probably only want to use getStringCellValue(), unless you're doing something like copying a spreadsheet and wish to retain any formatting. If that's the case, the XSSRichTextString object that is returned by getRichStringCellValue()  will contain any format information like **bold** or *italic*.

Answer (score 6):

From [Apache's Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html):

**getRichStringCellValue():**

> get the value of the cell as a string - for numeric cells we throw an
>   exception. For blank cells we return an empty string. For formulaCells
>   that are not string Formulas, we throw an exception.

**getStringCellValue():**

> get the value of the cell as a string - for numeric cells we throw an
>   exception.