# Excel double quote is not recognized in Apache POI

Tags: java, regex, excel, apache-poi, openoffice-calc

I'm using Apache POI API for reading excel(XLS/XLSX) file. Many of the cell contains String values for example 
     ***User has paid ”$22” in down payment*.**

After getting `cell.getStringCellValue()`, I'm matching the string with regular expression **`\"\\$\\d*\"`** to check any price element is present in the string or not.

Though the string contains element which matches the regex, it is not getting satisfied, because of the double quote **symbol (”)** is different in excel file where as in Java. The same string got matched with the regex, when it is used as `String str = "User has paid \"$22\" in down payment".`

How to resolve this ? Is the encoding of excel file and JVM is the causing the problem ?

Comment: try `(?:\"\\$\\d*\"|\”\\$\\d*\”)`

Comment: Avinash, It didn't help. I do not think it is problem of regex, it is the problem with the character(”) in excel vs character(") in java runtime. Look at the first char, that I have copied from excel file itself where as the second just typed.

Comment: yep i added a regex for that character also.

Comment: My concern is, what if many such characters having the same problem. How many patterns? So if there is a provision in the Apache POI API to take care of these symbols, it is easy going, isn't?

Comment: I've you tried [getRichStringCellValue() instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170275/what-is-the-difference-between-getrichstringcellvalue-and-getstringcellvalue)

Comment: Jonathan, getting as rich string also having the same issue. I think it might be the character encoding problem between excel and JVM.